# Contract deploy error with web3.py: Incorrect argument count

Tags: erc-20, web3.py

I am trying to deploy **ERC20** based token with **web3.py**. I successfully compiled the solidity contract, but get an error when I deploy. The exception is raised in this line:

```
tx_hash = contract.deploy(transaction={'from': w3.eth.accounts[2], 'gas': 410000})
```

The full deployment script:

```
   import json
    from web3 import Web3, HTTPProvider,TestRPCProvider
    from solc import compile_source, compile_files
    from web3.contract import ConciseContract

    compiled_sol = compile_files(["DappToken.sol"])
    # print(compiled_sol.keys())
    contract_interface = compiled_sol['DappToken.sol:DappToken']
    # print(contract_interface['bin'])
    # print(contract_interface)

    # web3.py instance
    w3 = Web3(Web3.HTTPProvider("http://127.0.0.1:7545"))
    # print(contract_interface['abi'])
    # Instantiate and deploy contract
    contract = w3.eth.contract(abi=contract_interface['abi'], bytecode=contract_interface['bin'])
    print(contract)
    # Get transaction hash from deployed contract
    # candidates = 'hello world'
    print(w3.eth.accounts[2])
    tx_hash = contract.deploy(transaction={'from': w3.eth.accounts[2], 'gas': 410000})
    # print(tx_hash)
    # Get tx receipt to get contract address
    tx_receipt = w3.eth.getTransactionReceipt(tx_hash)
    print(tx_receipt)
    contract_address = tx_receipt['contractAddress']

    # Contract instance in concise mode
    abi = contract_interface['abi']
    contract_instance = w3.eth.contract(address=contract_address, abi=abi, ContractFactoryClass=ConciseContract)



    contract_instance.functions.transfer({'to': w3.eth.accounts[1]}, 250000, {'form': w3.eth.accounts[0]})
```

The exception:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/anupam/Documents/workspace/Ethereum_Blockchain/py_intregreat_sol/py_intregrate_sol.py", line 21, in <module>
    tx_hash = contract.deploy(transaction={'from': w3.eth.accounts[2], 'gas': 410000})
  File "/home/anupam/Documents/workspace/Ethereum_Blockchain/py_intregreat_sol/py_eth/lib/python3.6/site-packages/web3/utils/decorators.py", line 57, in wrapper
    return to_wrap(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/anupam/Documents/workspace/Ethereum_Blockchain/py_intregreat_sol/py_eth/lib/python3.6/site-packages/web3/contract.py", line 323, in deploy
    deploy_transaction['data'] = cls._encode_constructor_data(args, kwargs)
  File "/home/anupam/Documents/workspace/Ethereum_Blockchain/py_intregreat_sol/py_eth/lib/python3.6/site-packages/web3/utils/decorators.py", line 16, in _wrapper
    return self.method(objtype, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/anupam/Documents/workspace/Ethereum_Blockchain/py_intregreat_sol/py_eth/lib/python3.6/site-packages/web3/contract.py", line 763, in _encode_constructor_data
    arguments = merge_args_and_kwargs(constructor_abi, args, kwargs)
  File "/home/anupam/Documents/workspace/Ethereum_Blockchain/py_intregreat_sol/py_eth/lib/python3.6/site-packages/web3/utils/abi.py", line 182, in merge_args_and_kwargs
    len(args) + len(kwargs),
TypeError: Incorrect argument count.  Expected '1'.  Got '0'
```

1. Why do I get this error?
2. Where are the mistakes in the code?

Comment: Are you sure your contract doesn't require any argument in the constructor?

Comment: No, I require argument in the constructor. I changes in code. Please check.

Answer (score 2):

### Try the newer constructor API

> I require argument in the constructor

To supply an argument to the constructor, I find the [newer constructor API](https://web3py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/contracts.html#web3.contract.Contract.constructor) to be more pleasant. Let's say the constructor takes the number of initial tokens, which you want to be 1000. That can be done with:

```
contract.constructor(1000).transact({'from': w3.eth.accounts[2], 'gas': 410000})
```

### Why didn't this approach work?

1. *Why do I get this error?* The error is telling you that you need to supply an argument to the constructor. No arguments were supplied.
2. *Where are the mistakes in the code?*

In the [old constructor API](https://web3py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/contracts.html#web3.contract.Contract.deploy) (the one used in the question), the appropriate way to pass in arguments would be:

```
contract.deploy(args=[1000], transaction={'from': w3.eth.accounts[2], 'gas': 410000})
```

Note that this syntax is deprecated, and will likely be removed in Web3.py v5.